# программа на electron работает неправильно, если запустить через ярлык

Tags: node.js, windows, exe, electron

Программа на electron работает неправильно, если запустить через ярлык. Если запускать напрямую, все отлично работает... Как так?

Comment: что по вашему *работает неправильно* и что значит *запустить напрямую*? как правило, всё работает *правильно*, просто запускают *неправильно*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема может быть в текущем каталоге. Когда вы запускаете программу напрямую (скажем, щелкаете по ней в Проводнике), текущим каталогом становится каталог самой программы. Когда вы запускаете через ярлык, может быть по-разному: если каталог не указан в свойствах ярлыка, текущим станет каталог самого ярлыка. Также в ярлыке можно установить дополнительные параметры запуска, в которых может быть ошибка. В общем, проверьте свойства ярлыка, нет ли там лишнего или не пропущено ли чего.

Comment: поставил галочку "запуск от имени администратора" в свойствах ярлыка. И все начало работать. Спасибо!